# Best way to track user activity from email to download

Tags: analytics, tracking, newsletter

I need to track users activities starting from an email campaign as in the following example:

I have pages X and Y where I have a few files that can be downloaded, let's call them FileA and FileB.

- **User1** clicks on the link, accesses **PageX** and downloads **FileA**.
- **User2** clicks on the link, accesses **PageX** and downloads **FileB**.
- **User1** then clicks on **PageY** (another page) and downloads **FileC**
- **User2** goes too to **pageY** but doesn't download anything.

I need a report that shows the following:
**User 1**:
pages visited: page X, page Y
files downloaded: FileA, FileC

**User 2**
pages visited: page X, page Y
files downloaded: FileB

What are the best tools to achieve this result?
Link clicks from email are obvious, any newsletter software achieves this, but how do I deal with the downloads?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a database for this purpose? You could define the following tables:

```
pages(id, name, url)
users(id, name, username, password, email)
event_types(id, name)
events(id, page_id, user_id, event_type_id, issued, additional)
```

You store your `X` and `Y` in pages. You store your users in `users`. You store visit and download in `event_types`. You store the actual events in `events`, knowing the `user_id`, `page_id`, `event_type_id` and you store the event date in `issued` and additional data (like downloaded file) in `additional`.

Next, you should write code, which stores the actual events whenever a user visits a page, or downloads a file. You query your tables to gather information. Also, beware [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [XSS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: casting id to (int) can prevent injection if he only wants to use the user id.

Comment: Yes, but probably he will want more complex things in the future, like storing some things in additional, given by the user. If he wants to track profile edit for username change, for instance (which is not part of the current question), storing the old and new username in additional, then SQL innjection will become a danger. It is better to prevent these problems as early as planning the feature.

Comment: So true. most of that can be done by MYSQLi, he also needs to be careful with XSS as well. :)

Comment: Yes, that one is also important. The op. needs to protect the project from XSS attacks, like <script type="text/javascript">/*my evil code*/</script>

Answer (score 0):

This needs lots of pages and techniques, but for start:

1. All your links in your emails must carry an id, MD5 is good if you want to have a database of users or use BASE64 to encode and decode user information
2. Once user clicked the link, from email or anywhere, track him/her into a click page.
3. Create a session for that user to record the activity.
4. Redirect user to your desired page.
5. Manipulate your files with a file that override header information.
6. Record which user want to download it from your session, then allow the file to be downloaded.
7. Generate a report from your recorded data for your users.

** Now it depends which language you want to implement these concepts.

** additional steps may require.